# From UML class diagram to Java : class hierarchy choices

Tags: java, inheritance, class-hierarchy

[image]

I'm trying to implement this in Java and I'm facing some interface / inheritance problems. I'm quite new to OO concepts so this will likely be an architecture choice / concept misunderstanding. If some information is missing, tell me and I'll try to make myself clearer.

Switches can be OSIL 2 or 3 equipments so I assume I need interfaces for the inheritance because one can only have on superclass at once, right ?
Problem : I cannot make Node an interface because I need its attribute and if it's not an interface OSIL3Equipement (as an interface) can't inherit from it.
Question : how can I model this in Java (aka where's the mistake in my class hierarchy ?)
(Italic written class names means its abstract, might be a convention but I prefer to point it out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So part of the issue is that switches are trying to do two different things at once. Would it be possible to model them separately? OSIL 2 Switch and OSIL3 Switch. (possibly with switch as the interface that both are implementing on top of their OSIL Equipment base class)

If it needs to be a single object, could can work around java's lack of multiple inheritance by turning one of the abtract classes into an interface, and letting each implementation of it define its own data structure. ie: OSIL2Equipment is an interface method with getARPTable() or doARPTableLookup(), and the Switch class would just define it as a private field.

Comment: Separate modelling with a switch interface sounds like an elegant solution on paper and works in my implementation. Thank you